# recall class if a condition is met (Python - Django)

Tags: python-3.x, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am using Django-rest-framework to create an API.
My API is something like:

```
class SampleApi(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        my_var = self.abc(request, firstname)
        self.xyz(request, lastname)
        if my_var == 0:
            **# call the api again**
        else:
            # Do other stuff
            pass

    @staticmethod
    def abc(request, firstname):
        # do some task
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def xyz(request, lastname):
        # do some task
        pass
```

I want to call the same api again if my if condition is matched.
Can anyone please guide me here. Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by calling the API again?

Comment: It is like, we call an API then we have some condition which changed our parameter values so we want to call the API again to get the output according to the new parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can recall that function.

```
class SampleApi(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        my_var = self.abc(request, firstname)
        self.xyz(request, lastname)
        if my_var == 0:
            self.get(request)
        else:
            # Do other stuff
            pass

    ...
```

Hope it could help.

Comment: this calls the API again but it is going on infinite loop

Comment: just once again?

Comment: Isn't there any condition for stopping recursive calls? The implementation is easy, so just let me know about the logic.